# text shadow in react native

Tags: react-native, shadow

in my site i have a title with this text shadow:

```css
h1.title {
 text-shadow: -1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="title">title</h1>
```

I want do the same in my react native app.

I've seen the properties:

```
textShadowColor color
textShadowOffset {width: number, height: number}
textShadowRadius number
```

but I don't knows how to have the same effect of html.

How can I do?

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#textshadowoffset)

Comment: You can add a shadow to a `<Text></Text>` by the following format
`textShadowColor: '#000',
textShadowOffset: { width: 0.5, height: 0.5 },
textShadowRadius: 1,`

Answer (score 124):

[CSS text-shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) has the below syntax,

> **text-shadow**: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;

To achieve similar effect with the css you provided you can use something like this,

```
// text-shadow: -1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)

{
  textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
  textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
  textShadowRadius: 10
}
```

Comment: A note to anybody still having trouble getting the text shadow to show - It seems that unlike in CSS you can't have a radius value of 0, try `textShadowRadius: 1` At least in Android this seems true, I haven't tried ios.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to stop the edge of the shadow being cut off by the edges of the text box? I have tries overflow:visible on it and all its parents but no luck.

Comment: @JamesTrickey, try adding some padding

Answer (score 25):

I tried sir bennygenel's answer and it worked.
I used it something like this...

```
<View>
    <Text style={styles.textWithShadow}>Hello world</Text>
</View>
```

.....

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     textWithShadow:{
         textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
         textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
         textShadowRadius: 10
     }
});
```

Comment: Is this really useful? You've basically copied and pasted the previous answer. Maybe you should post your revisions as a comment on the above answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that also but i cant write a comment. It says i must have at least 50 reputations. This won't happen again, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

I try like this in my react native app

```
<Text 
    style={{
        color: "white", 
        textShadowColor: 'black', 
        textShadowOffset: { width: -1, height: 0 },
        textShadowRadius: 10, 
        fontSize: hp('2%'), 
        fontWeight: '800'}}
    >
    Online Sports Store to Buy Sports Goods,
</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

- Please Review Bellow url it is help full for you.
- this site is shadow output with code.
- when you update Shadow Depth to automatically manage styles and showing the android and ios output.
- after you can copy the code and paste from your style like below example.

for EX:-

```
<Text 
    style={{
        shadowColor: "#000000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 3,
        },
        shadowOpacity:  0.17,
        shadowRadius: 3.05,
        elevation: 4,
      }}
    >
    This Is Button With Box Shadow
</Text>
```

[image]

=> https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Answer (score -2):

other methods didn't work well enough for me, this is more simple:-

```
    <h1  style={{color:'white', textShadow: "0px  0px  10px  black"}}>Your text here </h1>
```

I hope it helps someone out there!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is html where the user is looking for react-native